# Is there an “if on home page” type conditional? or force a block to show only on home page

Tags: blocks, static-block

I decide to use [Notification Bar](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/notification-bar-9180.html) extension to show a notification just in home page.
But this extension shows the notification on all pages.

I found that there is a notifications.phtml file in `app\design\frontend\base\default\template\notificationbar\html\`
with this content:

```
    <?php
/**
 * Datepicker adminhtml configuration control based on the 
 * Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Report_Config_Form_Field_YtdStart control.
 *
 * @author Justin Stern (www.foxrunsoftware.net)
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2012 All Rights Reserved, http://www.foxrunsoftware.net
 * @license    FoxRunSoftware License Agreement
 * 
 * THIS CODE AND INFORMATION ARE PROVIDED "AS IS" WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY 
 * KIND, EITHER EXPRESSED OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE
 * IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND/OR FITNESS FOR A
 * PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
 * 
 * @category design
 * @package  base_default
 */
?>
<?php
/**
 * @see FoxRunSoftware_NotificationBar_Block_Html_Notifications
 */
?>
<?php if ($this->displayNotifications()): ?>
    <div id="notification-bar"><div id="notification"><span class="notification-content"><?php echo $this->getNotificationContent(); ?></span><?php if($this->allowClearControl()) : ?><span class="notification-close"><a title="dismiss this notification">×</a></span><?php endif; ?></div></div>
    <?php if($this->allowClearControl()) : ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $$('#notification-bar .notification-close').first().observe('click',function(event) { var callback = <?php echo ($this->isFixed() ? "function() { \$\$('body').first().setStyle({marginTop:0}); }" : "function(){}") ?>; event.element().up('#notification-bar').fade({duration:0.5, afterFinish:callback}); Mage.Cookies.set("<?php echo $this->getNotificationClearCookieName() ?>","1",new Date((new Date()).getTime() + 365*24*60*60*1000),"/"); });
    </script>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I found that I should alter this line:

```
<?php if ($this->displayNotifications()): ?>
```

Is there some way to determine if the page being served is  home page?

Comment: Try this notification bar extension https://magecomp.com/magento-notification-bar.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to do this form the `local.xml`. This way we'll know for sure our changes will be included last.

So add the following in the `local.xml` removing it from ALL the pages and specifically adding it to just the CMS index (which is the homepage)

```
<default>
  <remove name="notificationbar_notifications"/>
</default>

<cms_index_index>
   <reference name="after_body_start">
      <block type="notificationbar/html_notifications" name="custom_notificationbar_notifications" template="notificationbar/html/notifications.phtml" />
   </reference>
</cms_index_index>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$routeName = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getRouteName();
$identifier = Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier();

if($routeName == 'cms' && $identifier == 'home') {
    // for code
}
```

Try it!